# Making a Typescript function with an optional default return value. How to define the type of the return value conditionally?

Tags: typescript, overriding, conditional-types

I'm trying to make a function that searches recursively through some XML nodes looking for a particular attribute, and can optionally return a default value. Something that I can call like this:

```
getCascadingProperty(node, "text", "DefaultText") 
// if it can find a value for "text" it returns it, otherwise it returns "DefaultText"
getCascadingProperty(node, "text")
// if it can find a value for "text" it returns it, otherwise it returns null (or undefined would be fine)
```

I want the function to have a return type that depends on whether the second parameter is included or not. If the second parameter is sent, it should have a return type of `string`; if not, it should have a return type of `string|null` or `string|undefined`. I've tried a few variants using different combinations of conditional types and function overloading but I keep getting stymied.

My current best version looks like this:

```
private static getCascadingProperty(node:XMLNode, prop:string, defaultValue:string):string
private static getCascadingProperty(node:XMLNode, prop:string, defaultValue:undefined = undefined):string|undefined
        {
            var val = XMLParser.getXMLNodeAttribute(node,prop)
            if (val)
            {
                return val
            }
            if (node.parentNode)
            {
                return XMLParser.getCascadingProperty(node.parentNode, prop, defaultValue)
            }
            return defaultValue
        }
```

But I've got a red underline on "defaultValue" in the recursion statement, saying `Argument of type 'undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'`. I'm out of ideas. Any alternative options would be gratefully received!

EDIT - SOLVED!

I realised my error with this function shortly after posting and tried a new approach which I eventually got to work. It now looks like this:

```
private static getCascadingProperty<T extends string|undefined>(node:XMLNode, prop:string, defaultValue?:T):string|T
        {
            var val = XMLParser.getXMLNodeAttribute(node,prop)
            if (val)
            {
                return val
            }
            if (node.parentNode)
            {
                return XMLParser.getCascadingProperty(node.parentNode, prop, defaultValue)
                 
            }
            return defaultValue as T
        }
```

I couldn't make it work at first but adding the final "as T" solved my final issues.

Comment: Good job on solving it! Though I would still advise you to look at an overloading functions solution since `as` can be avoided here, I think. Not sure if it will work for you since XMLParser and XMLNode are missing, however there is [my attempt](https://tsplay.dev/w1xx2W)